# How to include `NA` values in .json file

Tags: json, r

I have a big .Rdata file and I want to convert this file into .json format. I have used `tojson()` but it didn't create my desired format . Then I typed `stream_out(kn, file("ma3.json"))` in R console and it automatically created my desired format and saved it as json file with name "ma3" in my R working directory (`kn` is the Rdata file).

My file contains some attributes with `NA` value and when I converted to json format, these attributes have been missed from data. And they are really important.

My question is how can I do that with `stream_out`?

P.S : I don't want to use `ma3 <- toJSON(kn, .na = "null")`. Because it can not create my desired format.

Thanks

Comment: There are at least 3 packages in R that have the `toJSON` function. Please, indicate the one you are using. Also, give an example of `kn` and how you want to convert it in a JSON string.

Comment: I have used jsonlite .